# How to dowload/upload file to onedrive

Tags: upload, download, onedrive, live-sdk

I have dynamic xml maker program, it downloads some data on some sites and creates an xml file, then saves it in a debug folder. Now I need upload this xml file to my OneDrive, and I will make a Windows Phone 8 app for downloading this xml file.

I've been looking at microsoft.com and stackoverflow posts, but I can't understand **how to upload/download file without *user interaction*** (like ftp upload/download). My desktop app needs to automatically (2 times a day) refresh the xml file. I'm looking for ftp hosts and other host platforms, but their bandwidth is not enough (this file is 4mb and has an estimated daily download 3000 times: 400gb bw/month), and they limit the maximum number of simultaneous users to 200.

(I already have a client id/client pass from  https://account.live.com/developers/applications/appsettings/ )

Comment: Your data transmission scenario sounds like it might involve data throttling for that volume on the LiveSDK.  I'm not sure to the specific nature of the limits, but you might start seeing 420 response failures for extended usage.  Consider instead of just 'syncing' that file so rapidly that you use a modified stamp or other mechanism which can prevent unnecessary downloads, or consider compressing your data package to minimize the request overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LiveSDK only needs to pop the user dialog to the user for the first time authentication/authorization, as long as you request the scope  wl.offline_access you'll be able to refresh the auth token without popping another dialog that requires user interaction.

Comment: I am noob for windows live sdk, how to handle is :S